# Why is request module closing after giving an input?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am working on a project that finds if a user is available or not on Instagram, (Basically that's only one of the functions.)
To do that I use this code from requests:

```py
def start():
    clear() # Clears the previous input through the OS module
    print(inp + cut + "Stress them is booting...") # Inp + Cut are optional strings
    use = input("Who do you want to attack? Enter here: >> ") # We take the input from here (Specifically the user)
    response = requests.get("https://www.instagram.com/"+xuse+"/") # Check if the user exists, this does not work if you put @ in the beginning.
    if response.status_code == 404 :
        PrintFatalError("User could not be found, try again.") # The user wasn't found
    # Here the program stops and returns to the main program / input where I ask the user for a command.
    elif response.status_code == 200 :
        PrintFatalError("User " + use + " has been detected ! Proceed with the tool? ") # The user was found
        f = input(" ") # This is the point
        if f in "y":
            print ("Beginning") 
        else:
            print("Not a valid option, aborting.")    # I abort since I don't want a loop in this phase.
```

Some other info that might help:

1. The program is fully CLI, I don't use a GUI.
2. This program uses while loops instead of for loops, for many reasons.
   NOTE: `PrintFatalError` is a variable I created to display messages in red / green color. It still does not work with the classic `print("string")` way through.

Comment: How do you know it stops there? Does it print the error message that user couldn't be found?

Comment: Are you intentionally using `f in "y"` as a shortcut for `f == "y" or f == ""`? Because the two are equivalent.

Comment: What's the problem? You don't see any (error) message because you are cleaning the screen all the time?

Comment: if f in "y" just asks the user if he wants to proceed with the tool or if he just wants to leave it there.

Comment: I don't clear anything, since I see a prompt saying if I want to use the command to start the tool after I enter the username. (This tool has many commands that's why.)

Comment: So why do you think that `requests module closing`?

Comment: Either because it fails to return the code and that could be anything, that it does not work in the first place or that I've done some syntax error.